# Counting the number of floats in a list between a range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been stuck on this task for a while. I've managed to generate 1500 coordinates that give me a float between 0 and 2 (x,y), using the code below.

```
coordinates = [(random.random()*2.0, random.random()*2.0) for _ in range(15000)]
print(coordinates)
```

However now I need to create a counter that counts the number of floats between 0 and 1 and outputs it to the user. Ive tried using If statements and while loops. I've also had a snoop around the internet and am unable to find anything of use. Does anyone know how to work this out?

Kind regards.

Comment: what exactly did you try?

Comment: I doubt you did much cheking, but this is just simply a matter of check if the number is between 0 and 1.

Comment: I spent a lot of time looking at other people who have had similar problems to me , they did get answers but I was unable to apply them to my code due to me constantly getting a Type Eroor

Comment: I dont have much experience in python unfortunately, I'm currently in my first year of A levels

Comment: also javajav , how do I check 10,000 values individually to see whether theyre between 0 and 1

Comment: Do you want to count both floats in the coordinate pair separately? Note that you can't compare a coordinate pair to a float directly of course, which is possibly where you're getting type errors.

Comment: No 101, sorry I didn't state beforehand. Both of the floats in the pair shouldn't be counted. If the x coordinate is between 0 and 1 then the counter should be appended by 1. If the x coordinate is above 1 then nothing should be added to the counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple conditional [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) over your tuples and sum up *1* if `x` or/and `y` are smaller then `1`:

```
import random

# your code used 15k tuples, your text says 1.5k - adapt the number to your liking
coordinates = [(random.random()*2.0, random.random()*2.0) for _ in range(1500)]

one_lower_1  = sum(1 for x,y in coordinates if x < 1 or  y < 1)
both_lower_1 = sum(1 for x,y in coordinates if x < 1 and y < 1)
x_lower_1    = sum(1 for x,_ in coordinates if x < 1)
y_lower_1    = sum(1 for _,y in coordinates if y < 1)

print(one_lower_1)
print(both_lower_1)
print(x_lower_1)
print(y_lower_1)
```

Output

```
1134
383
745
772
```

This is essentially a generator expression that filters out only those pairs that match the part after `if ....` from your generated `coordinates`

---

I choose the `sum(1 ... )` approach because that way you do not have to create a list to take its `len()`  ... it is more memory friendly if you just need the count of elements then producing all the elements.

---

Alternate way from [jpp's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9209546/jpp) comment:

```
sum(x < 1 or  y < 1 for x,y in coordinates)
```

this works because a sum over 10 `True` 's give 10 - each [True counting as 1](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

```
print(sum(True for _ in range(10))) # 10
```

Comment: You can also use the fact `bool` is a subclass of `int`, e.g. `sum(x < 1 and y < 1 for x,y in coordinates)`

Comment: @jpp neat one - added it

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. It's another list comprehension checking your list of coordinate pairs to see if each x and y is within the interval (0,1).

```
from random import random

print(len([(x,y) for x,y in [(2*random(),2*random()) for _ in range(1500)] if 0 < x < 1 and 0 < y < 1]))
```

If your only goal is to count all the pairs such that the x,y pairs are in the interval (0,1) then while loop would be more efficient by avoiding creating lists.

```
def rand_coordinates(num_of_pairs):
"""Counts the number of randomly generated x,y 
pairs in the range of [0,2) where x and y are 
contained in the interval from (0,1)"""
count = 0
while num_of_pairs:
    x,y = 2*random(),2*random()
    if 0 < x < 1 and 0 < y < 1:
        count += 1
    num_of_pairs -= 1
return count
```