# Creating a counter for a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys a amateur at python here.
I've got the following code below that I have coded.

```
for _ in range(10):
    x = random.random()
    print("Your x coordinates are",x)
    y = random.random()
    print("Your y coordinates are",y)
    distance = x**2 + y**2
    distance2 = math.sqrt(distance)
    print("The distance of your pair of points is",distance2)
```

It prints 10 randomly generated coordinates and calculates the distance of each pair using Pythagoras (monte carlo simulation). 
I've now created a counter named:

```
inside = 0
```

This counter needs to increment by 1 everytime the distance of a pair of coordinates is between 0 and 1. If the distance is above one the counter will not increment. I've had a go at this using while loops and if statements but I can't get the hang of it. Can someone please help?

Kind regards.

Comment: `count = 0 while(count < 10): #loop body  count+=1`.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @Sarah what part do you not understand, have you tried any of the answers offered below?

Answer (score 3):

```
inside = 0

for _ in range(10):
  ...
  if distance2 <= 1:
    inside += 1
```

That should sort ya out !

edit: I removed the `0 <=` check since it's a square root it'll always be larger than 0

Comment: it's not printing me anything :(

Comment: yup cos I didn't add any printing in there :) - what do you want it to print ? the total ? then add `print("The total number inside was", inside)` or similar

Comment: I did a print print(inside) but it didn't print anything.

Comment: actually, it either prints 0 or 10

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar approach as in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354839/7505395) to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354679/counting-the-number-of-floats-in-a-list-between-a-range-in-python):

You simply sum up all things from your data that are True (== 1) via [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
import random

data = [ (random.random(),random.random()) for _ in range(10)]

# sum up all points from data that are <=1 (and hence `True`)    
c = sum(x**2+y**2 <= 1 for x,y in data)
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#       if True then 1 else 0

print(data)
print(c)
print([x**2+y**2 for x,y in data])
```

Output:

```
 # data
[(0.7871534669693369, 0.6834268129613957), (0.6927388543591473, 0.7409611739266033),
 (0.8941640299899396, 0.31599794785329216), (0.8694462709965218, 0.5685622773035531),
 (0.5840557539431463, 0.08050013228900998), (0.7337702725369145, 0.5132161897225319), 
 (0.3972195311920842, 0.663522783123498), (0.6079754465427372, 0.3265026876981836), 
 (0.7599701022860814, 0.6681620505952428), (0.1663292844826113, 0.20439662041341333)]

# amount of points <= 1
6

# the distances to compare it 
[1.0866827892364175, 1.028910581605514, 0.8993840155753416, 1.0791998813223598, 
 0.3476013950126452, 0.8018096702522117, 0.5980458396844117, 0.47623814867297826,
 1.0239950822243569, 0.06944340931292242]
```

Comment: that's the method I used first and my code was working but my teacher said I can't use this method strangely enough

Comment: @Sarah *sigh* ... at least remove the `sqrt` - its not needed. Any sum > 1 will have sqrt-values also > 1 - any sum thats <1 will have parts that are also < 1 ... no need to use a computationally heavy method at all...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your way. If I understood correctly, you want to count the distance between 0 and 1.

```
distance = []
for _ in range(10):
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    distance1 = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    print(distance1)
    #print(x, y, distance1)
    distance.append(str(distance1))

counter = 0
count ={}
for i in distance:
    if (float(i)< 1):
        count[i] = i
        if i in count:
            counter += 1
```

print(counter)